# What is the difference between Visual Studio Express Edition and Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a windows forms application and just found out I cannot create an installer with "Visual Studio Express Edition " but I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Are these the same thing?

Comment: a quick google search will reveal much. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onecode/2014/11/12/differences-between-visual-studio-community-edition-and-express-editions/ https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

Comment: Jeremy okay, they're different. But can I add an installer in community?

Comment: Have you tried WIx? http://wixtoolset.org/ I believe it can be integrated with it

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Community edition has the same features as the Visual Studio Professional edition. The main question is do you meet the terms of the [community license](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547).